# getActiveWorkbenchWindow returns null in WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows()

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have the following code in my `WorkbenchAdvisor` subclasse's `openWindows()` override:

```
public class MyWorkbenchAdvisor extends WorkbenchAdvisor {
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean openWindows() {
        super.openWindows();
        PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().syncExec(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                IWorkbenchWindow win = 
                    PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();   
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I debug the code, I am seeing that after the call to `getActiveWorkbenchWindow()`, `win` is `null`. I did notice that by using `asyncExec` instead of `syncExec`, I can get `win` to initialize properly.  However, I do believe I need `syncExec` in my particular context.

As a side note, I have also tried not using `asyncExec`/`syncExec` altogether as well (a.k.a just put call to `getActiveWorkbenchWindow()` directly in the `openWindows()` method), but to no avail.

Help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible that you use `postStartup()` instead of `openWindows()`? In `postStartup()` `win` will not be `null`.

`openWindows()` is called too early there is no active workbench around, the reason why you got an active window using `asyncExec()` is because it is executed delayed. Which would be very buggy code, since it is not guaranteed that the active workbench is ready and so `win` could be `null` at one startup and not `null` in another.